# NeoVim Markdown CodeBlock completion

Tags: neovim

So recently I looked at some of those off the shelf NeoVim configs (LazyVim), and I found that they had lsp support in Markdown Code Blocks. I wanted to ask how it was possible to achieve that?

I read some of the source code of those off the shelf solutions but couldn't find anything matching.

Comment: How to get LSP-support and completion for Markdow Codeblocks?

Comment: _"I found that they had lsp support"_: so it is no longer there?

Comment: No it's just that I use my own neovim config and would like to have the LSP in the Markdown CodeBlocks as well.

Comment: Please post the link to the config.

Comment: Mine or the one i've got it from?

Comment: The config where markdown completion works.

Comment: [here](https://github.com/LazyVim/LazyVim)

Comment: The config uses hrsh7th/nvim-cmp but I do not see any sources what would indicate completion support inside markdown. Please provide some strong evidence that it actually works.